# Cannot eXit from Nano with Control + X in Visual Studio Code Terminal. Is there another shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, shortcut, nano

`Control + X` doesn't work to exit Nano in Visual Studio Code Terminal (I'm on Mac). I've edited a file, then saved it with `Control + O`. Works fine. But when I try to eXit Nano in the terminal it doesn't work. Is there another shortcut?

Comment: Please, add the output when you pressed Control + X. Just stating that it doesn't work isn't that helpful. Did the terminal freeze? Did it trigger another behavior? Additionally, you may add the specs of your editor and computer so that people reproduce the bug in the same environment.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to deny chord keybindings in the terminal.

Open your preferences, go to Features, Terminal and then uncheck "Integrated: Allow Chords". If you like better to edit the settings JSON, just put this there: `"terminal.integrated.allowChords": false`.